# DJANGO python error return qs._result_cache[0]

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, python-object

Im new using Django, Im coding for an ecommerce and everything is working as expected but an error raised even when the code is working!

Sorry for spanglish:

```
id = request.POST.get('id')
tamano = request.POST.get('size')
items = request.POST.get('items')
precio = request.POST.get('prize')
urlFoto = Producto.objects.filter(id=id).values("urlFoto")
nombre = Producto.objects.filter(id=id).values("nombre")
item = ItemCarrito(id, tamano, items, precio, urlFoto[0]['urlFoto'], nombre[0]['nombre'])
print(item)
controlCambio=False
if request.session.get('lista'):
    lista = request.session.get('lista')
    for posicion in range(0, len(lista)) :
        if lista[posicion].idItem == id and lista[posicion].variante1 == tamano:
            lista[posicion].unidades = int(item.unidades) + int(lista[posicion].unidades)
            print("HAY IGUALES")
            controlCambio=True
    if controlCambio==False:
        lista.append(item)

else:
    lista = []
    lista.append(item)

request.session["lista"] = lista
sumaPrecioCarrito(request, precio)
return detalleProducto(request, id)
```

The error appears in this line:

```
item = ItemCarrito(id, tamano, items, precio, urlFoto[0]['urlFoto'], nombre[0]['nombre'])
```

And it says:

```
 return qs._result_cache[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In that line I only create the object ITEM which constructor is:

```
class ItemCarrito:

def __init__(self, idItem, variante, unidades, precio, urlFoto, nombre):
    self.idItem = idItem
    self.variante1 = variante
    self.unidades = unidades
    self.precio = precio
    self.urlFoto = urlFoto
    self.nombre = nombre
```

Do you have some ideas of why this error is appearing but everything is working well?

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when you filter a QuerySet that yields 0 rows and try to use a non-existing index on said QuerySet.

Internally Django will try to run something like

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id=1) # A filter that returns an empty QuerySet
qs.query.set_limit(index, index + 1) # SELECT * from myapp_amymodel WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
return qs[0]
```

In this example, `OFFSET` value is going to be whatever index you are trying to access on your QuerySet in order to return just one row.

To answer the question, you need to check `urlFoto` and `nombre` are non-empty before calling `ItemCarrito` with those parameters.